Change word header numbering - numbering keeps resetting back to 1.X
When I try to change the formatting for numbered sections, it reverts automatically.
I am writing my chapters in separate documents. I would like to have the second chapter start all numbering with 2.X but it automatically is set at 1.X.
Microsoft Word for Mac
Version: 16.84 (24041420)
Screen capture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jyx8su3VfTd5Tc9IxDSe_eyQpDKlvJ03/view?usp=sharing
I looked online and found instructions on how to change the starting point. Format -> Bullets and Numbering -> Outlined Numbering -> Customize -> Level -> 2 -> OK
It works, but when I move away from it, even just to scroll, it automatically reverts to 1.X.

See https://superuser.com/questions/1609025/importing-numbered-paragraph-styles-in-word/1609033#1609033 https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680

Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is off-topic here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the Microsoft Community https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Thanks @CharlesKenyon for the link to that superuser!!! I will give it a try. I didn't understand the nuance of what MS Word questions were allowed here
